# Exit status in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to create script which can let me to put number of port as parameter and then find the name of service for this port.
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -E "\W$1\/" /etc/services | awk '{ print $1 }'
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
echo "Service(s) is(are) found correctly!"
else
echo "There is(are) no such service(s)!"
fi
```

Everything works perfectly but there is one problem. If I type such port as 99999 (or another fiction port) - "exit status" for `grep -E "\W$1\/" /etc/services | awk '{ print $1 }'` also will be 0. In this way all results of my scripts will be correct and `else` statement in my script won't work. What am I going to do to find the solution to this problem and let my `else` works fine with "exit status"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `grep` here at all, `awk` can do the pattern match on the port number.

`awk` can also keep track of whether the port was found or not and exit with an appropriate exit code.

For example:

```
$ port=23
$ awk  '$2 ~ /^'"$port"'\// {print $1 ; found=1} END {exit !found}' /etc/services 
telnet
$ echo $?
0

$ port=99999
$ awk  '$2 ~ /^'"$port"'\// {print $1 ; found=1} END {exit !found}' /etc/services 
$ echo $?
1
```

The `exit !found` works because `awk` variables default to zero (or true) if they haven't previously been defined - `exit !0` is `exit 1`.  So if we set `found=1` when we match then `exit !found` in the END block is `exit 0`.

Here's how to use that awk script with your if/then/else.

```
#!/bin/bash

awk  '$2 ~ /^'"$1"'\// {print $1 ; found=1} END {exit !found}' /etc/services 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "Service(s) is(are) found correctly!"
else
    echo "There is(are) no such service(s)!"
fi
```

You can also do it like this:

```
if awk  '$2 ~ /^'"$1"'\// {print $1;found=1} END{exit !found}' /etc/services ; then 
    echo "Service(s) is(are) found correctly!"
else
    echo "There is(are) no such service(s)!"
fi
```

Or even like this:

```
awk  '$2 ~ /^'"$1"'\// {print $1 ; found=1} END {exit !found}' /etc/services \
  && echo "Service(s) is(are) found correctly!" \
  || echo "There is(are) no such service(s)!"
```

Comment: it is a cool solution!Thanks! but I want to find the way to do it with `if-then-else` and `grep`.

Comment: You can use that `awk` script with if.  i'll edit my answer to show an example.

Comment: I am not good at awk. Could you tell me please what this part of code `$2 ~` in `awk` means ?

Comment: That compares ONLY the second field of `/etc/services` against the port regex, preventing any possibility of spurious matches from any comments on the input lines.  that's not a big risk with this particular input file but as a general rule if you know what you're searching for is in a particular field, it's good practice to restrict the search to just that field.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=$(sed -ne"\|^\([^ ]*\) *\($1\)/.*|!d;h;s//\2/p;g" \
        -e's||Found service: \1|w /dev/fd/2' -eq </etc/services)
exit "$((!${x:?No service found for: "$1"}))"
```